# What's the difference between New Blank Window and Popup in Javascript terms

Tags: javascript

Hello again StackOverflow Community:

**I need to prevent my site from being opened in traditional popup windows** (due to some fraud prevention issues, since the site is an ad network and fraud can be carried by automatically loading ads within popup windows). By popup windows I mean the small floating ones opened like: `window.open(URL, name, options)`. At first I was checking for the `window.opener` property, like:

`if (window.opener !== null && window.opener !== undefined) {

    window.self.close();

}`

But that obviously *also* closes a normal blank window (from `target='_blank'`) and thus the site cannot be shared in Facebook or Twitter where an external link is loaded in a blank window. **Is there a way to know when a new window specifically was a popup window.** I was thinking of doing the code above but checking for properties commonly disabled in popups, like toolbars, statusbar, etc. Example:

`if (window.toolbar.visible !== true && other window properties are checked) {

    window.self.close();

}`

**Is this approach right? What other ideas can be used?**
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I think if you really want to only your domain access the page, then why do not give access only to your server execute that page / pop-up. Of course inside of a structure control ... something like: if this is popup, then execute the verification --- is it my server? if yes execute otherwise DENY!

Comment: @Fernando Costa: It's not a matter of limiting access only from my domain; in fact, I want the site to be accessed from a lot of places. The thing is to prevent fraud, since the site is an ad network, and fraud can be carried by rapidly and automatically loading ads within _popup_ windows, which can even be small enough. Sorry if I wasn't clear about the nature of this problem, and I do thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a fool's errand if you ask me.

- Impossible to weed out false-positives
- Most browsers won't obey `window.close()` if the opener is from a different domain
- Would fail if javascript was disabled

Comment: Not necessarily a fool's errand. Two things: 1) If Javascript were disabled, then how come the person would be able to open a popup via Javascript in the first place. 2) At least Firefox and Chrome do obey window.close() when opened from a different domain; this is why I'm having troubles when posting a link to Facebook, Twitter, and other sites.